# Disable a class using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am using a e-commerce package and there are sections my client wants disable to hidden.  The problem is the package has all their labels under the same class and I am not sure how I can target certain ones in order to hide or disable them.

I have 5  and would like to hide the 3rd one, lets say.  They are in a table to so it looks just like this:

```
<td><span class="lable">Description</span></td>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.label').eq(2).hide()
```

Prefer the the list selection methods like `eq()` to the non-standard selectors like `:eq`. Using the jQuery selectors makes the browser fall back to the relatively slow Sizzle selector library instead of the fast native `querySelectorAll()` support built into modern browsers.

Comment: +1 Very elegant. And very interesting information about what goes on under the hood. Could you point where such inside knowledge is found?

Comment: line 3530 in jquery 1.4.2 source, plus the [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) spec. Unfortunately the jQuery docs don't spell out the implications for performance, but IMO using non-CSS selectors is questionable in itself. If a later CSS version comes along and defines one of the Sizzle/jQuery selectors with a slightly different meaning, we're all in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've tagged this as jQuery, then the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), [`gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [`lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selectors may be of interest to you:

```
$("tr > td > span[class=lable]:eq(2)").hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6MvnB/

and: http://jsfiddle.net/LD6nU/ (courtesy of @Majid)

Comment: +1 Very good selector, but I changed your code slightly to: `$("tr > td > span[class=lable]:eq(2)").hide();` It just hides the 3rd one not all greater than the 3rd as your selector does. But surely it is still your answer. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/LD6nU/

Comment: @Majid - Thank you. Somehow I got it into my head that he wanted everything after the whateverth to be hidden (I think I must have got that impression from sample markup which looks like a header row).